# How can I have floated list items display their bullet in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I've got a list with floated list items which should use the standard bullet.  But in IE7 only, these bullets don't appear:

Here is the all the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>

<style type="text/css">
/*ul { overflow: hidden; margin: 1em; padding: 1em; } */
ul li
  { width: 30%;
    float: left;
    border: dashed red 1px;
/*  list-style-position: outside; list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 1em; padding: 1em; zoom: 1; */
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit </li>
    <li>consectetuer adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>Etiam sapien neque</li>
    <li>dictum at</li>
    <li>bibendum ut</li>
    <li>posuere quis</li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

The commented-out CSS are rules that I tried, but which didn't make the bullets appear.

When I remove the `float: left;` declaration, the bullets do appear in IE7.

How can I get floated lis with bullets to display in IE7?

Comment: `list-style-position: inside` might work, I think `outside` is the default. Failing that try adjusting the `margin-left` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use a workaround to get the bullets to display in IE7.  I created an image of the bullet, and set it as the background-image for the LIs, along with some extra padding.

I would be happy to accept another answer though! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Further to my comment (to the question), a demo is posted over at [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/afivi5).

With the following CSS seems to achieve your aims:

```
ul li {
float: left;
list-style-position: inside;
margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}
```

Comment: That code and JSBin demo displays the bullet in Firefox3, but not in IE7.

Comment: @KatieK, *darn*, I'm not sure why that is, but I'll get back to you on that. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the bullets disappear in Safari on MacOS, as well...  I found [a page](http://venutip.com/content/disappearing-bullets-ie) that, in one of the comments, gave me a solution that worked for me: Putting a `display: list-item;` style onto `a` or `span` tags when they occur inside an `li`, like this:

***CSS:***

```
ul li {
    width: 30%; /* or whatever; copying your example */
    float: left;
}

ul li a, ul li span {
    display: list-item;
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="some/thing">link to something</a></li>
  <li><span>not a link</span></li>
  <li> ... [oops, no bullet!] </li>
</ul>
```

Note that in the case of an `a` tag, the bullet will be part of the link (and colored as one, etc.).  With span (and removing the `ul li a` styling), that should be avoidable.

Sadly, this does mean changing your markup... but at least it's hopefully not an entirely unreasonable type of change.

Also of note: this works with `ol` lists, too, with an interesting caveat: If you stop floating them (and thus they get their normal numbering back), you end up with each item numbered twice!  So, be careful of doing this to all `li a` or `li span` combinations; perhaps you'd want to use a class for lists that would be treated this way, and only apply these stylings to that.  For example, one might change the above to:

```
.floated li { width: 30%; float: left; }
.floated li a, .floated li span { display: list-item; }
```

I hope this helps (if not the original questioner, this being so old, then someone, sometime).