# Conflict between bullets and float:left in IE7

Tags: css, css-float

This issue appears in Internet Explorer and I have not been able to resolve it:

```
#test ul li {
list-style-type: disc;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

The code above works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE7 it's not displaying the bullets.

I have tried deactivating the attribute `float: left` and the bullets are displaying, but the list is vertical. My list must be aligned horizontally with the bullets.

I have tried add the follow attributes:

- `list-style-position: inside` and outside and nothing.
- using `display: inline` makes the bullets disappear.

```
#test ul {
list-style-type: disc
}
```

- and nothing

I have tried changing the margin with different values, adding padding with different values, and nothing.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of another question, which I've just added an answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622757/how-can-i-have-floated-list-items-display-their-bullet-in-ie7/18337398#18337398

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `li`s inline and the `list-style` of the `ul` to `none` and then emulate the bullets using the `:before` pseudo element:

```
ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
}
li {
display: inline;
}
li::before {
content: "o ";
}
```

Of course, instead of "o" you could use an unicode character representing a bullet.

Comment: I tested the code and I can't see the bullet "0", anything bullet.  Thanks for your answer and your help.

Comment: I tried my code here: http://result.dabblet.com/gist/3361854/9f1c58d7b3005dcc799658093e900c9db40cc6e0 everything works as expected to me. What browser do you use?

Comment: Hi Matthias.  Thanks.  I have tested this url and looks so in IE7: http://screencast.com/t/s5WoDkGMPJV.  Thanks again

Comment: Sorry for that. I first thought that IE7 would support `:before`. But unfortunately I am not able to test IE because I'm using linux.

Comment: No problem. I'll continue searching a solution. I thank your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create the bullet with an image and set it as the background.

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
 ul{
    list-style:disc outside none;
    padding:0px;
    padding-left:12px;
    margin-left:8px;
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vkRdc/1/)

Comment: But I have IE7 in my pc installed and I have tested this in it. Plus double checked in IETester. I think you have some problem in you font with the special characters.

Comment: I don't believe an issue related with the font because if I delete the option float:left, the bullet is shown.  If I enable the float:left the bullet is not shown, I need the option float:left because , the list keeps horizontal.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

might be a bit late but including a span tag inside with display:list-item seems to fix the problem when the margin and padding adjustment fails..refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337398/1776573. It worked for me when the margin and padding adjustments dint solve the issue..